# Create hyperlink from Prezi presentation to Zotero item

Tags: hyperlink, prezi

It is possible to open Zotero items directly via an exported link, as described [here](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/24241/linking-to-zotero-items-via-zotero-select).

The link takes this form: `zotero://open-pdf/library/items/your-item-code`. This link can be copy/pasted into a browser, or defined as a clickable link in various Windows documents.

I would like to insert such a link into a Prezi presentation to create mind maps from my Zotero literature data base. Unfortunately, Prezi only accepts web hyperlinks in the usual URL format. Adding a Zotero link in the described format produces gibberish. Any ideas on how to make the Zotero link understandable to Prezi?